# Need RPi3b voice control

Tags: gpio, pi-3b+, led

I'm failing to find a simple way to control my RPi via microphone. I've fount some projects but they all require things such as Google AIY voice kit. Is there any simple way for me to control GPIO pins or run commands via prerecorded voice commands. If you know of a way or any existing projects I'd really appreciate if you could share it, as I cannot find one. Thank you.

Comment: You could use [mycroft](https://mycroft.ai/get-mycroft/), but you will have to write your own skill.

Answer (score 1):

I've no direct experience of it, but Jasper may be work a look.

http://jasperproject.github.io/#about

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer with a link; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed or you risk to get down votes.